# Deep Link not automatically opening in Android

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking

I've set up a Deep Link within an app. When a notification comes through with a deep link, the User is prompted with a popup asking which app they would like to open the link with.

Both of these apps are identical, I only have one instance of it installed on my device.

[image: image of android popup asking for which app to open link with]

Here's a snippet of my AndroidManifest

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="myscheme"
                    android:host="foo" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

The deep link I am using is `myscheme://foo`

Here's the entire AndroidManifest - one thing to note, the package name and the URI scheme are identical, `myscheme`.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="myscheme">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="myscheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you mean to say both same app are displayed?

Comment: @GauravRoy - that's correct. Both apps behind the black rectangle are the same app.

Comment: are you sure about there are no 2 apps installed? ahve you tried in some other phone

Comment: I am certain, if I open the deep link with the second app in the popup, I remain within my current app and the link goes nowhere. Clicking the first one works as expected.

Comment: very very strange,never seen this. curious to know also. ill check if i get something

Comment: Could you share the manifest completely?

Comment: @Sina - I've updated with the complete manifest file.

Comment: @Dan Since you've mentioned package attribute is same as the scheme of the intent filter, have you checked if changing the scheme to something else has any effect on the problem you are facing?

Comment: @Dan Hi again. Several questions: 1. Is it important to you that the dialog get shown? 2. Are you by any chance targeting android 6 or higher? 3. Do you see this issue on Samsung devices? 4. Do you have more than 1 module in your application?

Comment: What if you use a different Activity for handling the link?

Comment: @Sina - your point regarding the same bundle identifier and URI scheme was the problem here. I changed the URI scheme and everything worked as expected.

Comment: Glad to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Android App Links intent-filter, while you should be using a URI scheme intent filter

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="foo"
                    android:scheme="myscheme" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you able explain the difference between your answer and the `<intent-filter>` that I am using please?

Comment: Yeah, sure. You should try removing the  `android:autoVerify="true"` in the `intent-filter` section header. Can you pls try and report back? Thanks :)